# how to find the size of a div in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, size, height

i am trying to figure this out:

i have some html and php:

```
<div class="main" style="height: 800px">
    <div class="head" style="height: 300px"</div>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        for ($i=0; $i<=$size;$i++){
            echo "<div style="/"height: 20px;/">line $i</div>";
        }
        ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

now, what i am trying to do is to find the height of the `.container` div and apply it to `$size`

if the `.container` height is 100 then i will do something like: `$size = 100 / 20` or something similar.

The issue is that even if i find the div height it is still on the client side and i might have to do some ajax.

Another problem is that if there is no content in the `.container` usually there is no height.

in this case i could force the size of `.container` to be `800 - 300` but i don't allays know other sizes from different block elements on the page.

i hope i am not to confuse with this question.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can't make operation with php on client side. It muts be parsed on the server side. Javascript will do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `height()` and `width()` method to get the size.

Check out the sample and **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/QZCue/)**

#### Sample

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    MyContent<br><br>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
alert($(".container").height())
alert($(".container").width())
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/QZCue/)**
- [jQuery.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
- [jQuery.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)